# Reading a zip file within a jar file

Tags: java, jar, zip

Previously we had some zip files within our web application. We would want to pares a specific text document within the zip file. This wasn't a problem:

```
URL url = getClass().getResource(zipfile);
ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(url.getFile().replaceAll("%20", " "));     
Entry entry = zip.getEntry("file.txt");

InputStream is = zip.getInputStream(entry);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

String line = reader.readLine();
while (line != null) {
    // do stuff
}
```

However we've moved these zip files into another module and want to package them within a jar. Unfortunately, creating the `ZipFile` now fails. I can get an `InputStream` for the zip: but I have no way of getting an input stream for the entry itself.

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream(zipfile);
ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(is);

ZipEntry entry = zis.getNextEntry();
while (entry != null && !entry.getName().equals("file.txt")) {
    entry = zis.getNextEntry();
}
```

but I have no way of getting an input stream for the entry itself. I tried finding the length of the entry and getting the next n bytes from the `ZipInputStream` but this didn't work for me. It seemed all bytes read were 0.

Is there a way round this or am I going to have to move the zip files back into the core project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

entry can give you the inputstream of the inner-zip file.

```
InputStream innerzipstream = zip.getInputStream(entry);
```

So you can use

```
new ZipInputStream(innerzipstream);
```

and ask the ZipInputStream to retrieve the content of the inner-zip-file (in an ordered fashion, you don't have random access because it's a ZipInputStream)

Look at http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html

**Sequential zip access**

As ZipInputStream is reading a zip file from an input stream it has to do things in order:

```
// DO THIS for each entry
ZipEntry e = zipInputStreamObj.getNextEntry();
e.getName // and all data
int size = e.getSize(); // the byte count
while (size > 0) {
   size -= zipInputStreamObj.read(...);
}
zipInputStreamObj.closeEntry();
// DO THIS END

zipInputStreamObj.close();
```

**Note:** I don't know if ZipInputStream.getNextEntry() returns null when end of zip file is reached or not. I hope so because I don't know other way to realize when there are no more entries.

Comment: In fact, you can use Class.getResourceAsStream and ZipInputStream to read the outer-zip too. That way, you don't need the ad-hoc file name replace and don't rely on URL for file access.

Answer (score 7):

How about TrueZip? Using it you could simply open the zipped file as if it was located inside a directory.

```
new FileOutputStream("/path/to/some-jar.jar/internal/zip/file.zip/myfile.txt");
```

According to the docs, infinite nesting is also supported. I have yet to actually use this project, but it's been on my radar for a while and it seems applicable to your problem.

Project Site: http://truezip.java.net/ (edited)

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the Sequential Zip access code provided above:

```
File destFile = new File(destDir, jarName);
JarOutputStream jos = new JarOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(destFile));

JarInputStream jis = new JarInputStream(is);
JarEntry jarEntry = jis.getNextJarEntry();
for (; jarEntry != null ; jarEntry = jis.getNextJarEntry()) {
    jos.putNextEntry(new JarEntry(jarEntry.getName()));
    if(jarEntry.isDirectory()) {
       continue;
    }

    int bytesRead = jis.read(buffer);
    while(bytesRead != -1) {
    jos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    bytesRead = jis.read(buffer);
    }

}
is.close();
jis.close();
jos.flush();
jos.closeEntry();
jos.close();
```

In the above code, I am trying to copy a Jar file inside another Jar file to a folder in  file system.
'is' is the input stream to the jar file inside another jar file (jar.getInputStream("lib/abcd.jar"))

Answer (score 0):

it is also possible to parse the string and open an ZipInputStream on another ZipInputStream and set the entry to the file inside.

e.g. you have the String like above "path/to/some-jar.jar/internal/zip/file.zip/myfile.txt"

```
private static final String[] zipFiles = new String[] { ".zip", ".jar" };

public static InputStream getResourceAsStream(final String ref) throws IOException {
    String abstractPath = ref.replace("\\", "/");
    if (abstractPath.startsWith("/")) {
        abstractPath = abstractPath.substring(1);
    }
    final String[] pathElements = abstractPath.split("/");
    return getResourceAsStream(null, pathElements);
}

private static InputStream getResourceAsStream(final ZipInputStream parentStream, final String[] pathElements)
        throws IOException {

    if (pathElements.length == 0) return parentStream;

    final StringBuilder nextFile = new StringBuilder();
    for (int index = 0; index < pathElements.length; index++) {
        final String pathElement = pathElements[index];
        nextFile.append((index > 0 ? "/" : "") + pathElement);
        if (pathElement.contains(".")) {
            final String path = nextFile.toString();
            if (checkForZip(pathElement)) {
                final String[] restPath = new String[pathElements.length - index - 1];
                System.arraycopy(pathElements, index + 1, restPath, 0, restPath.length);
                if (parentStream != null) {
                    setZipToEntry(parentStream, path);
                    return getResourceAsStream(new ZipInputStream(parentStream), restPath);
                } else return getResourceAsStream(new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(path)), restPath);
            } else {
                if (parentStream != null) {
                    setZipToEntry(parentStream, path);
                    return parentStream;
                } else return new FileInputStream(path);
            }
        }
    }
    throw new FileNotFoundException("File not found: " + nextFile.toString());
}

private static void setZipToEntry(final ZipInputStream in, final String name) throws IOException {
    ZipEntry entry;
    while ((entry = in.getNextEntry()) != null) {
        if (entry.getName().equals(name)) return;
    }
    throw new FileNotFoundException("File not found: " + name);
}

private static boolean checkForZip(final String ref) {
    for (final String zipFile : zipFiles) {
        if (ref.endsWith(zipFile)) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```