# use java class to load Applicationcontext.xml present inside jar

Tags: java, spring, jar

i have a jar named SpringPoc.jar which i have exported using eclipse as a  runnable jar

inside the jar i have 2 classes
 one is

```
public class NormalServlet {

    public void executeScheduler() {        
         ApplicationContext context = 
                 new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("com/serv/Beans.xml");

          CallMeth obj = (CallMeth) context.getBean("callMeth");
          obj.test();       
    }}
```

2nd class is Main App

```
public class MainApp {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("com/serv/Beans.xml");

    CallMeth obj = (CallMeth) context.getBean("callMeth");
    obj.test();
}}
```

i have defined a single bean inside Beans.xml

```
 <bean id="callMeth" class="com.poc.CallMeth"/>
```

then i have created a simple java project in eclipse having a test class
which calls the jar and tries to execute the above class NormalServlet

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            URL[] classLoaderUrls =  new URL[]{new URL("file:\\D:\\MyWorkspace\\Scheduler\\src\\com\\callit\\SpringPoc.jar")};
             URLClassLoader urlClassLoader = new URLClassLoader(classLoaderUrls);

                Class classToLoad = Class.forName ("com.serv.NormalServlet", true, urlClassLoader);
                Method method = classToLoad.getDeclaredMethod ("executeScheduler");
                Object instance = classToLoad.newInstance ();
                Object result = method.invoke (instance);   

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

when i run test class

i get the below error

```
Sep 09, 2016 11:48:30 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@1c50507: startup date [Fri Sep 09 11:48:30 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
Sep 09, 2016 11:48:30 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [com/serv/Beans.xml]
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.callit.Scheduler.callMe(Scheduler.java:40)
    at com.callit.Scheduler.main(Scheduler.java:15)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [com/serv/Beans.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [com/serv/Beans.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:343)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:216)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:251)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:540)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:454)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.serv.NormalServlet.executeScheduler(NormalServlet.java:17)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [com/serv/Beans.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:329)
    ... 19 more
```

if i run the same jar from cmd 
as java -jar SprrinPoc.jar
the MainApp class is called and the Beans.xml loads fine

Question is why doesn't it load when i call Normalservlet externally from test class

Thanks a lot

Comment: where is you XML file located?

Comment: @Jens xml is located under com.serv package here the NomalServlet class exists

Comment: Try to add a slash in front of the path

Comment: tried  ApplicationContext context =  new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/com/serv/Beans.xml"); getting exception Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [com/serv/Beans.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [com/serv/Beans.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Answer (score 0):

As long as the dependency jar has file included xxx.xml, it should be available in your host project classpath as well.  This will search applicationcontext.xml anywhere in classpath

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            "classpath*:**/applicationContext.xml");
```

Comment: tried ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            "classpath*:**/beans.xml"); it throws a nobeanfound exception . but i think it doesn't load the xml .  cause i modified the above code as ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            "classpath*:**/beans1.xml"); .note : i have no xml named beans1.xml  ... still it threw a nobeanfoundexception

Comment: exact exception Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'callMeth' is defined

Comment: then is it is possibly not loaded, are you sure, your jar available in classpath?

Comment: jar is at a separate location .i am using the below code to work on the jar  URL[] classLoaderUrls =  new URL[]{new URL("file:\\D:\\MyWorkspace\\Scheduler\\src\\com\\callit\\SpringPoc.jar")};it is able to find the jar and invoke the method(executeScheduler) in the class NormalServlet but ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("com/serv/Beans.xml"); is not able to ind the Beans.xml

Comment: then you should be using FileSystemXmlApplicationContext

Comment: if i use FileSystemXmlApplicationContext  then it tries to find the xml under D:\MyWorkspace\Scheduler\ which is wong xml is inside the jar......exception is INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from file [D:\MyWorkspace\Scheduler\com\serv\Beans.xml] Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from file [D:\MyWorkspace\Scheduler\com\serv\Beans.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: com\serv\Beans.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)

Comment: you need to load the jar file from zipinputstream. check similar questions here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17515757/reading-files-within-a-jarzipinputstream-etc ,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710615/reading-a-zip-file-within-a-jar-file